# About a function of bounded variation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, bounded-variation

If $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}$ is of bounded variation. Let be $f^+(x)=\max\{f(x),0\}$ and $f^-(x)=\max\{-f(x),0\}$, then $f^+,f^-$ are functions of bounded variation. It is true? I know the inverse is true.

Answer (score 0):

**The statement is true**: let's prove it, by first recalling some elementary properties of positive and negative parts $f^+$ and $f^-$ of a given function $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}$. 
$$
\begin{split}
  f&=f^+-f^-\\
  |f|&=f^++f^-
\end{split} \iff 
\begin{split}
  f^+&=\frac{1}{2}\big(f-|f|\big)\\
  f^-&=\frac{1}{2}\big(|f|-f\big)
\end{split}\tag{1}\label{1}
$$

From \eqref{1}, recalling that $BV([a,b])$ is a (topological) vector (as a matter of fact, Banach) space (see for example Natanson (1983), §8.3, pp.216-217, theorem 3), we can prove that $f\in BV([a,b])$ implies $f^+,f^-\in BV([a,b])$ by proving that the former property implies $|f|\in BV([a,b])$: that's precisely what we'll do below.

**Definition 1**. A function $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}$ is said to be of *bounded variation*, symbolized as $f\in BV([a,b])$, if
$$
V_a^b(f)=\sup_{P \in \mathscr{P}} \sum_{i=0}^{n_{P}-1} | f(x_{i+1})-f(x_i) |<\infty
$$
where

- $P$ is a [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_an_interval) of $[a,b]$ and
- $\mathscr{P}$ is the set of all partitions of the same interval.

**Lemma**. If $f\in BV([a,b])$ then $|f|\in  BV([a,b])$.

**Proof**. $f\in  BV([a,b])$ implies that $V_a^b(f)<\infty$ 
$$
\begin{split}
V_a^b(f)&=\sup_{P \in \mathscr{P}} \sum_{i=0}^{n_{P}-1} | f(x_{i+1})-f(x_i) |\\
&\geq \sup_{P \in \mathscr{P}} \sum_{i=0}^{n_{P}-1} \big| |f(x_{i+1})|-|f(x_i)| \big|\\
&=V_a^b(|f|)
\end{split}
$$
therefore $|f|\in BV([a,b])$. $\blacksquare$

Then, by the vector space properties of $BV([a,b])$, 
$$
f\in BV([a,b])\:\Longrightarrow
\begin{split}
  f^+&=\frac{1}{2}\big(f-|f|\big)\in BV([a,b])\\
  f^-&=\frac{1}{2}\big(|f|-f\big)\in BV([a,b])
\end{split}
$$
**Notes**

- It is not necessary to have a look at one of the classical monographs in real analysis in order to prove that $BV([a,b])$ is a vector space: the property follow easily from the definition of bounded variation ad from the [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality), by proceeding in a  similar way to what is done in the above lemma.
- Again the above lemma, jointly with other standard propositions, implies that
  $$
  f\in BV([a,b])\iff|f|\in BV([a,b])\iff f^+,f^-\in BV([a,b])
  $$

[1] Natanson, I. P. (1983)[1961] "*Theory of Functions of a Real Variable*", revised ed., New York: Ungar, pp. 277, ISBN 0-8044-7012, MR 0067952, Zbl 0064.29102.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a self contained argument:

If $h:=f+g$ then one has for all $x$ and $y$ the inequalities
$$|h(x)-h(y)|\leq|f(x)-f(y)|+|g(x)-g(y)|,\quad \bigl|\,|f(x)|-|f(y)|\,\bigr|\leq|f(x)-f(y)|\ .$$
From this we  can immediately conclude that when both $f$ and $g$ are of bounded variation on an interval $[a,b]$ then so are $f+g$ and $|f|$.

It remains to note that
$$f^+={1\over2}\bigl(|f|+f\bigr),\qquad f^-={1\over2}\bigl(|f|-f\bigr)\ .$$